# MATLAB when integrating from acceleration to velocity to position I am getting very high y values

Tags: android, matlab, accelerometer, numerical-integration

I am getting raw acceleration data from an accelerometer and am trying to double integrate it in order to get the position.

The android phone used to get the data is set on a flat surface for 3 seconds to diminish drift. I take the mean of acceleration over the resting period to zero out the beginning. This worked out fine, but when we integrate to velocity and position (using cumtrapz) we are getting unrealistically high y values (meters/s for velocity and meters for position.)

The raw data is waving the phone at a certain tempo.

Does anyone have ideas on why the position gets such high values?
Below are the graphs showing what I described as well as my code.

Edit: Even when the phones is not rotated, the values are unrealistic and not indicative of how the phone moved. In the attached pictures, the phone was moved in the shape of a box on a flat surface with no rotation involved.

```
 %VarName2 = accelerometer values in X direction
    %VarName3 = accelerometer values in Y direction
    %VarName4 = accelerometer values in Z direction
    %elapsedArray = time values for each sample of accelerometer data

    ddx = VarName2 - mean(VarName2(1:limit));
    ddx = ddx(1:length(ddx)-200);
    elapsedArray = elapsedArray(1:length(elapsedArray)-200);
    ddy = VarName3 - mean(VarName3(1:limit));
    ddy = ddy(1:length(ddy)-200);
    ddz = VarName4 - mean(VarName4(1:limit));
    ddz = ddz(1:length(ddz)-200);

    velX = cumtrapz(ddx .* elapsedArray);
    velY = cumtrapz(ddy .* elapsedArray);
    velZ = cumtrapz(ddz .* elapsedArray);

    dx = velX - mean(velX(1:limit));
    dy = velY - mean(velY(1:limit));
    dz = velZ - mean(velZ(1:limit));

    posX = cumtrapz(dx .* elapsedArray);
    posY = cumtrapz(dy .* elapsedArray);
    posZ = cumtrapz(dz .* elapsedArray);

    x = posX - mean(posX(1:limit));
    y = posY - mean(posY(1:limit));
    z = posZ - mean(posZ(1:limit));

    figure;
    plot(ddx);
    title('Acceleration in X')
    xlabel('Time (sec)')
    ylabel('Acc (meters squared');

    figure;
    plot(dx);
    title('Velocity in X')
    xlabel('Time (sec)')
    ylabel('Velocity (meters)');

    figure;
    plot(x);
    title('Position X')
    xlabel('Time (sec)')
    ylabel('Position (meters)');

    figure;
    plot(y);
    title('Position Y')
    xlabel('Time (sec)')
    ylabel('Position (meters)');

    figure;
    plot(z);
    title('Position Z')
    xlabel('Time (sec)')
    ylabel('Position (meters)');
```

**Acceleration in X direction**

[image: Acceleration in X direction]

**Velocity and Position in X direction**

[image: Velocity and Position in X direction]

[image: Acceleration of Box test in X direction]

[image: Velocity of Box test in X direction]

[image: Position of Box test in X direction]

Comment: Are you sure that initial plot is *actually* acceleration? Also what is the sampling period of your accelerometer? I'm assuming your x axis is wrong here (i.e. you weren't shaking the phone for 13 minutes straight). If you were though, at what frequency were you shaking the phone? (you may be way undersampling in time)

Comment: Yes, the initial plot is acceleration since it samples directly from the accelerometer. 

The sampling period samples approximately every 100th of a second and the x axis is the indexes of the time array, so they correspond to every 1/100th of a second as well. The x-axis label still says seconds from a previous test - apologies.

Comment: Are you sure you are not rotating the phone while shaking it? The accelerometer is measuring along a fixed axis, and if you rotate the phone the x-axis in this coordinate frame is not constant during your sampling window (with respect to an earth-fixed frame).

Comment: There was some rotation in the tempo test, but would it account for the strange velocity and position values? We also got strange results when testing the phone by just moving it along a flat surface with no rotation.

Comment: Given your acceleration plot, the velocity and position intuitively seem correct to me.  Just looking at acceleration, most of the area between the curve and the x axis is above the x-axis.  If you were truly shaking the phone back and forth, you would expect a symmetric distribution around the x-axis such that your mean acceleration/velocity/position is zero.  So your acceleration data is bad, possibly from undersampling (which sounds unlikely, given your explanation), or just a poor quality accelerometer.

Comment: One sanity check for this particular experiment (the shaking experiment) would be to check that the number of acceleration data samples >0 is about the same as the number < 0.  If this distribution is skewed, you will see a large position / velocity offset in the direction with the most data points.

Comment: I performed the sanity check and got 905 positive acceleration and 194 negative acceleration. So this does seem to be the problem, so I will look further into sampling the accelerometer data correctly and understanding why there is more positive data than negative

Comment: Why are you multiplying the acceleration (and also the velocity!) by the elapsed time vector?  Just run `cumtrapz` over the acceleration values, and multiply the final result by your sample time.

Comment: I think @mikkola was on to something.  I would try the experiment again, but make sure you shake the phone when it is perfectly level.

Comment: The accelerometers in most of these devices are used to derive the device **orientation** (which is a (semi) static state) based on the projection of gravity on the accelerometers axis, not for inertial navigation. So to reduce error and noise, the accelerometer output in these devices is heavily (low pass) filtered. The effective bandwidth you get is probably minimal, so if you shake your device too fast you will miss a lot of actual acceleration content.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the result of time drift.  Let's assume that the accelerometer readings you are measuring have a very small error, dErr, at every time point.  Once you integrate these values to get velocity, the error at each time point will be multiplied by a factor t.  Integrating a second time to get position will cause the original error to be multiplied by a factor of t^2.  Therefore, the error at each time point will propogate at dErr(t)*t^2.

In order to get a good estimate for position, you can try to incorporate prior information about position, but will likely have to use a combination of accelerometer and gyroscope data.  You might also have to look into Kalman Filters.

Here is a Google Tech Talk explaining this issue:
https://youtu.be/C7JQ7Rpwn2k?t=23m33s

Comment: While this is a real phenomenon, this is not the explanation for the OP's results.  As you can see, the results for the table-top experiment look quite good, and do not suffer from the drift problem.  It takes much longer to accumulate that much drift error than the time frame for the OP's experiment.

Comment: I have already worked on a problem like this where I tried to estimate position using accelerometer values on an android watch.  The sensors are not accurate enough to give a good estimate of position and the drift errors do add up in the short time frame.  Here is another post on this topic: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/156192/accelerometer-double-integration-error

Comment: Interesting...a good point in this post  that was also made by @mikkola about the gravity component of acceleration.